# Is there an Raspberry Pi OS designed for a small screen

Tags: pi-2

I have a B raspberry pi and I want an OS that works well with small screens. The raspian OS isn't working well with my 5" screen. The graphics is the correct resolution, I don't need help with that, but the windows and text are too big. Can someone recommend a solution(preferably a OS specifically designed for use on small screens) I know how to do this and already have done it:
`overscan_left=24
overscan_right=24
Overscan_top=10
Overscan_bottom=24
Framebuffer_width=480
Framebuffer_height=320`
but I can't use programs effectively with the size of things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a similar setup and I ran the command `dpkg --reconfigure console-setup`. This will bring up a list of options regarding the font of the system, including the size.

For the GUI I believe there is a Openbox menu that has options for changing the font size of folders for example.

Comment: I could use that I guess if it could change the right things. Does it help using things like Sonic Pi on a small screen?

Comment: I'll just try it :P

Comment: @DavidC. Sorry for the delay..I believe it only works for the console... the openbox menu I believe will help although Sonic Pi is a very big application. btw a tip, if you find you need to reach part of a window that isn't visible on the screen, use left alt, left click and it will let you move the window without having to be clicking on the decorations.

Comment: Okay, but my real problem is the fact Raspian is designed for a bigger screen than mine. The reason I asked for an OS is because a OS for a small screen would have things easier to read, with features more suited to it, such as not having everything on one place :P I guess I'll have to wait or make my own solution.

Comment: @DavidC. If you want to learn about a very popular window manager and design your desktop from scratch you could look into Openbox. I did that starting from a very minimal version of Raspbian called Minibian. This way you basically control everything font size, icon size, layout etc. This is probably the way to go. Programs themselves though like you were talking about Sonic Pi, cannot be adjusted that much by themselves AFAIK unless you recompile them which is insane if you want to do that for every program on your system. Beyond that, Im at the end of my knowledge :).

Comment: aww... Well i'm going to have to use my Raspberry A for coding :P

Answer (score 3):

Try editing your `/boot/config.txt`file and changing `disable_overscan = 1` 
and something like this for the following lines

```
overscan_left=24
overscan_right=24
Overscan_top=10
Overscan_bottom=24

Framebuffer_width=480
Framebuffer_height=320

Sdtv_mode=2
Sdtv_aspect=2
```

Comment: The question is about text size, not screen placement. I'm not sure how this answers the question in any way.

Comment: "The graphics is the correct resolution, I don't need help with that"